# Connection reset by peer - pub/sub API

Tags: api, platform-event, grpc

I am working on a cli for the pub/sub api to subscribe to platform evetns. The app is being wrote in rust using tonic. I am recving an error though - `tonic::transport::Error(Transport, hyper::Error(Connect, Os { code: 104, kind: ConnectionReset, message: "Connection reset by peer" }))'`. Below is my code.

```rust
fn stream_fetch_request(event: String, num: i32) -> impl Stream<Item = FetchRequest> {
    // creates a request with default value
    let mut request = FetchRequest::default();

    // sets the topic name
    request.topic_name = format!("/event/{}", event);

    //sets the number requested
    request.num_requested = num;

    // turn the request into an iter and return it
    tokio_stream::iter(1..usize::MAX).map(move |_| request.clone())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // grabs the inputs from the user
    let input_details = InputDetails::retrieve();

    // gets the events passed in from user
    let events = &input_details.events;

    // gets the access token and other org details
    let salesforce_details = input_details.clone().get_access_token().await.unwrap();

    // gets the org id
    let org_id = salesforce_details.get_org_id().await;

    // the next three lines configure the tls cert
    let pem = tokio::fs::read("ca.pem").await.unwrap();

    let ca = Certificate::from_pem(pem);

    let tls = ClientTlsConfig::new()
        .ca_certificate(ca)
        .domain_name("example.com");

    // creates the channel to connect to
    let channel = Channel::builder("https://api.pubsub.salesforce.com:7443".parse().unwrap())
        .tls_config(tls)
        .unwrap()
        .connect()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    // the next three lines set the auth metadata
    let token: MetadataValue<_> = salesforce_details.access_token.parse().unwrap();

    let instance_url: MetadataValue<_> = salesforce_details.instance_url.parse().unwrap();

    let tenant_id: MetadataValue<_> = org_id.parse().unwrap();

    // setups the client with an interceptor to set the auth metadata
    let mut client = PubSubClient::with_interceptor(channel, move |mut req: Request<()>| {
        req.metadata_mut().insert("accesstoken", token.clone());
        req.metadata_mut()
            .insert("instanceurl", instance_url.clone());
        req.metadata_mut().insert("tenantid", tenant_id.clone());
        Ok(req)
    });

    // creates the request streams for the first event passed in.
    let request_iter = stream_fetch_request(events.get(0).unwrap().clone(), 200).take(200);

    // sends the request - it fails on the unwrap here
    let stream = client.subscribe(request_iter).await.unwrap().into_inner();

    // we accept 200 responses from the server
    let mut stream = stream.take(200);

    // loop through each response
    while let Some(item) = stream.next().await {
        println!("\treceived: {:#?}", item.unwrap().events);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your domain is not `example.com`.  Channel can be constructed in a slightly simpler fashion - see [example](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/src/tls/client.rs).

Comment: I used example.com since I don’t want to share my domain on stack exchange. It is a streaming request so the request sent in has to implement Stream<Item = FetchRequest>

Comment: This is not your domain. Think about how SSL works and take a look at `ClientTlsConfig` docs